# Repeating an alarm to fire exact at specific time not work correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm to fire everyday at specific time ex: 8:00am
but alarm manager not fire at exact time sometime after 2 minute of specific time and sometime more than that .

My code

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle("notification title")
            .setContentInfo("info")
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)


    val notifManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    notifManager.notify(0, builder.build())
}

companion object {

    fun startAlarmManager(context: Context, hour: Int, minute: Int = 0) {
        // set time for alarm manager
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

        if (calendar.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis())
            calendar.timeInMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

        // set up alarm manager
        val alarmReceiver = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmReceiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent)

        context.toast("started")
    }

    fun stopAlarmManager(context: Context) {
        // set up alarm manager
        val alarmReceiver = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmReceiver, 0)
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

    }


}
```

}

when i use

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis,pendingIntent)
```

It work fine and notification send exact at specific time 
One more thing, I have already read this question but not solve my problem .

[Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)

[Alarm Manager not working at specific given time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474721/alarm-manager-not-working-at-specific-given-time-interval)

and also

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: "when I use <..> it works fine"  what is the problem then

Comment: `setRepeating()` hasn't been exact since KitKat. You need to use an exact method, and schedule the next alarm each time it fires.

Comment: Mike M : Thank you so much , that what i was miss .

Comment: Tim Castelijns :Thank you for caring ,  I need to know why setRepeating(..) not work like setExact(...) and Mike M. answer my question .